# how to email generated pdf from @react-pdf/renderer

Tags: reactjs, pdf

I have a react project that creates a pdf from `@react-pdf/renderer`. I want the pdf to be emailed when user clicked a button. I tried converting the pdf to Blob but it didn't work.

```
const sendEmail = async () => { 
    try { 
        const pdfBlob = new Blob([<CustomPdf coupon={coupon} type={type}/>], { type: 'application/pdf' }, `My PDF_${formattedDate}.pdf`);  
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('from', 'example@yahoo.com');
        formData.append('to', 'example@gmail.com');
        formData.append('subject', 'Your Subject');
        formData.append('text', 'Your email content');
        formData.append('attachment', pdfBlob); 
        const response = await axios.post(
            `https://api.example.net/v3/${domain}/messages`,
            formData,
            {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(`example:${apiKey}`)}`,
            },
            }
        ); 
        console.log('Email sent:', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending email:', error.response);
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you wanting to use `mailto:`, raw SMTP, or a third-party e-mail web-service like Mailchimp?

Comment: @Dai Im using Mailgun. Is there any significant differences using it over other?